# How to override GetRootPath for Nancy bootstrapper?

Tags: .net, f#, nancy

My try:

```
type Bootstrapper() =
    inherit DefaultNancyBootstrapper()
    interface IRootPathProvider with
        override i.GetRootPath() = Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

Errors :

> No implementation was given for 'IHideObjectMembers.Equals(obj: obj) :
>   bool'. Note that all interface members must be implemented and listed
>   under an appropriate 'interface' declaration, e.g. 'interface ... with
>   member ...'. error FS0366: No implementation was given for
>   'IHideObjectMembers.GetHashCode() :

...

possible realization :

```
type Bootstrapper() =
    inherit DefaultNancyBootstrapper()
    interface IRootPathProvider with
        member i.Equals o = true
        member i.GetHashCode() = 0
        member i.GetType() = typedefof<int>
        member i.ToString() = ""
        member i.GetRootPath() = Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

but I still don't know what should I pass there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also provide implementations for the inherited interfaces see the definition:

```
public interface IRootPathProvider : IHideObjectMembers
```

you haven't given functions for the `IHideObjectMembers` interface - as the error message has pointed out.

Also, you don't need override with interfaces

Comment: Are there any examples of `IHideObjectMembers` implementation? It seems sane but I can't find anything in documentation / samples about it.

Comment: I don't know about examples - but it appears this interface is just a trick to tidy up the intellisense when you are using C#.

Comment: I see, so I still don't know what I supposed to pass there but thanks anyways.

Comment: I don't know the first thing about F#, but IHideObjectMembers should just map to the corresponding Object that implements it. Essentially all it does is define and interface that contains the standard Object methods, and marks them as non-editor-browsable, so they should (in theory) vanish from intellisense. It's a trick for fluent APIs, or for anywhere where you don't want the intellisense muddied with irrelevant methods. AFAIK it's non-CLS compliant though, which might explain the foibles with F#.